# List all items that are of the same type

Tags: python, function, class, for-loop, methods

I'm creating a function in a class wherein when I search for an item type for instance a car type then it will list all items that falls under the type car. I'm able to print just one item but not all. It should return 2 if two are found but it only list one. Output returns items of the same type in a Tuple with a bool. What should I change on my code?

```
    def get_item(self, types1):
        for types2 in self.all_items:
            if types2.toy_type.lower() == types1.lower():
                output = (bool, [types2.name])
                return output
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the return statement outside the for loop, otherwise it returns only the first toy name.

```
def get_item(self, types1):
    output = []
    for types2 in self.all_items:
        if types2.toy_type.lower() == types1.lower():
            output.append((bool, [types2.name]))
    return output
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to create an empty list at the start of the function and each time you find a toy of the type you are looking fo, you should add it to the list

```
def get_toy(self, types1):
    output =[]
    for types2 in self.all_toys:
        if types2.toy_type.lower() == types1.lower():
            output.append((bool, [types2.name]))
    return output
```

Comment: Your answer is identical to the other one

Comment: yeah, I just saw someone posted an identical code 2 minutes before I did, I gave a different explanation tho ¯\_(ツ)_/¯, do you think this is enough for my answer to staying or should I delete it since its the same code? (I honestly don't know since I am new here )

thank you in advance :)